# Using pipe (%>%) based on function parameter?

Tags: r, dplyr, shiny, tidyverse, shinyapps

I'm trying to conditionally add the pipe to make a slice max or slice min, based on the function parameter. Could you help me?

```
library(magrittr)

generates_data_graph <- function(data, positive = FALSE) { 

 data_graph <- data %>%
    {if (positive)
        slice_max(order_by = value1, n = 5) %>% 
        mutate(chave1 = fct_reorder(.f = key1, .x = value2, .desc = TRUE))  
     else 
        slice_min(order_by = value1, n = 5) %>% 
        mutate(chave1 = fct_reorder(.f = key1, .x = value2, .desc = FALSE)) 
    }
}
```

Another question, this will slow my code? Because this can be done by:

```
generates_data_graph <- function(data, positive = FALSE) { 


   if (positive) {
        data_graph <- data %>%
        slice_max(order_by = value1, n = 5) %>% 
        mutate(chave1 = fct_reorder(.f = key1, .x = value2, .desc = TRUE))

   }

   else {
        data_graph <- data %>%
        slice_min(order_by = value1, n = 5) %>% 
        mutate(chave1 = fct_reorder(.f = key1, .x = value2, .desc = FALSE))

   } 
        
}
```

But the second way I will need to copy and paste code, it's not good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions are objects in R, so you could simply assign the right function to a variable and call it later:

```r
generates_data_graph <- function(data, positive = FALSE) { 
  slice_fn <- if (positive) slice_max else slice_min
  data_graph <- data %>%
    slice_fn(order_by = value1, n = 5) %>% 
    mutate(chave1 = fct_reorder(.f = key1, .x = value2, .desc = TRUE))
}
```

Comment: The `.desc` argument changes so you need to define that in `if/else` clause as well

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!! Do you know if, in shiny apps, this will slower my code?

Comment: Very few things can further slow shiny down! The if/else clause above certainly won't :) However, @Baraliuh is right that I've forgotten to change the value of `.desc` -- well, you could easily do it using the same clause (or perhaps set `.desc = !positive`)